# Foreach exploded string is stopped

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

Im working on eshop (like) script which after payment add you to DB access to content.
I use PHP 5 and MySQL

## Introduction into the problem

1. I have two strings. Each has some values separated by comma. Something like this - `testValue1,testValue2,TestValue3`.
2. I use explode function on this two string to make arrays. Exploding by comma works perfectly.
3. Foreach value from first array i look into DB if user has something like in his products, **if not -> write it**, **if yes -> write it after DB content**.
4. **HERE** appears the problem. Script works perfectly instead one thing. Foreach loop exit after first run. It write into db correct values but only one of them.

### What i want to

```
$stringOne = "testProduct1,testProduct2";
```

User in DB -> Products ->  `testProduct1#testProduct2`

(I separate products by **#** for my own reasons)

### What i really get

```
$stringOne = "testProduct1,testProduct2";
```

User in DB -> Products ->  `testProduct1`

## Code

```
$array_mesta = explode(',', $mesta);
$array_ceny = explode(',', $ff['ceny']);
//$ff['ceny'] and $mesta are string which i get from DB few rows above

foreach($array_mesta as $key => $mesto) {

    if (strpos($array_ceny[$key],'6 měsíců') !== false) {
        $delka = '183';
    }
    if (strpos($array_ceny[$key],'12 měsíců') !== false) {
        $delka = '365';
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM makleri WHERE email = '".$email."'";
    $sth = mysql_query($query);
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {

        $level = $r['level'];
        $od = $r['od'];
        $do = $r['do'];

        if ((strpos($level,'#') !== false) or ($level !== "null")) {
            echo "už v db něco má, zapíšu zato /n";
            $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE makleri SET level = '".$mesto."#rok', od = '".$od."#0"."', do = '".$do."#".$delka." WHERE email = '".$email."'");
        }
        else {
            echo "nic v db nemá, vše přepíšu /n";
            $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE makleri SET level = '".$mesto."', od = '0', do = '".$delka."' WHERE email = '".$email."'");
        }
    }       
}/* foreach */
```

### Update Whole function

```
function processPayment() {
    self::setState(GopayHelper::PAID);

    $orderNumber = self::getOrderNumber();
    $email = self::getEmail();


    $ss = "SELECT * FROM procesy WHERE orderNumber = '$orderNumber'";
    $jqr2 = mysql_query($ss);
    while($ff = mysql_fetch_assoc($jqr2)) {

        $prevodni_tabulka = Array('ä'=>'a', 'Ä'=>'A', 'á'=>'a', 'Á'=>'A', 'à'=>'a', 'À'=>'A',
                                  'ã'=>'a', 'Ã'=>'A', 'â'=>'a', 'Â'=>'A', 'č'=>'c', 'Č'=>'C',
                                  'ć'=>'c', 'Ć'=>'C', 'ď'=>'d', 'Ď'=>'D', 'ě'=>'e', 'Ě'=>'E',
                                  'é'=>'e', 'É'=>'E', 'ë'=>'e', 'Ë'=>'E', 'è'=>'e', 'È'=>'E',
                                  'ê'=>'e', 'Ê'=>'E', 'í'=>'i', 'Í'=>'I', 'ï'=>'i', 'Ï'=>'I',
                                  'ì'=>'i', 'Ì'=>'I', 'î'=>'i', 'Î'=>'I', 'ľ'=>'l', 'Ľ'=>'L',
                                  'ĺ'=>'l', 'Ĺ'=>'L', 'ń'=>'n', 'Ń'=>'N', 'ň'=>'n', 'Ň'=>'N',
                                  'ñ'=>'n', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'ó'=>'o', 'Ó'=>'O', 'ö'=>'o', 'Ö'=>'O',
                                  'ô'=>'o', 'Ô'=>'O', 'ò'=>'o', 'Ò'=>'O', 'õ'=>'o', 'Õ'=>'O',
                                  'ő'=>'o', 'Ő'=>'O', 'ř'=>'r', 'Ř'=>'R', 'ŕ'=>'r', 'Ŕ'=>'R',
                                  'š'=>'s', 'Š'=>'S', 'ś'=>'s', 'Ś'=>'S', 'ť'=>'t', 'Ť'=>'T',
                                  'ú'=>'u', 'Ú'=>'U', 'ů'=>'u', 'Ů'=>'U', 'ü'=>'u', 'Ü'=>'U',
                                  'ù'=>'u', 'Ù'=>'U', 'ũ'=>'u', 'Ũ'=>'U', 'û'=>'u', 'Û'=>'U',
                                  'ý'=>'y', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'ž'=>'z', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ź'=>'z', 'Ź'=>'Z'
                                  ); 
        $mesta = strtr($ff['mesta'], $prevodni_tabulka);

        $array_mesta = explode(',', $mesta);
        $array_ceny = explode(',', $ff['ceny']);

        foreach($array_mesta as $key => $mesto) {

            if (strpos($array_ceny[$key],'6 měsíců') !== false) {
                $delka = '183';
            }
            if (strpos($array_ceny[$key],'12 měsíců') !== false) {
                $delka = '365';
            }

            $query = "SELECT * FROM makleri WHERE email = '".$email."'";
            $sth = mysql_query($query);
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {

                $level = $r['level'];
                $od = $r['od'];
                $do = $r['do'];

                if ((strpos($level,'#') !== false) or ($level !== "null")) {
                    echo "už v db něco má, zapíšu zato /n";
                    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE makleri SET level = '".$mesto."#rok', od = '".$od."#0"."', do = '".$do."#".$delka." WHERE email = '".$email."'");
                }
                else {
                    echo "nic v db nemá, vše přepíšu /n";
                    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE makleri SET level = '".$mesto."', od = '0', do = '".$delka."' WHERE email = '".$email."'");
                }
            }
        }/* foreach */
    }/* while */
}
```

#### DB VALUES

```
$ff['mesta'] = "Brno,Praha,Olomouc";
$ff['ceny'] = "12 měsíců - Cena za měsíc - 100 Kč bez DPH,6 měsíců - Cena za měsíc - 100 Kč bez DPH,6 měsíců - Cena za měsíc - 100 Kč bez DPH";
```

output from **$level, $od, $do** after foreach :

```
$level = "Brno";
$od = "0";
$do = "365";
```

Comment: you should check the php run time, because maybe the php is faster than your DB runtime.

Comment: You wrote _Foreach value from first array i look into DB if user has something like in his products_. But your query doesn't look for the value from the first array in the DB, it looks for `$email`.

Comment: Please post the whole function code for us to check the values of each variables and also add some real values from database.

Comment: I edited my question. U can see whole function now. @Barmar i look for email only for row, but after it i get $level variable which means - $product or restriction level.

Comment: Which `UPDATE` are you expecting to be executed with that `$level`? It's executing the first one because `$level !== "null"` is true.

Comment: It would be helpful if you used the same variables in your description of the code and the code itself. What is `$stringOne`? What is `User in DB -> Products`?

Comment: Your `if ((strpos($level,'#') !== false) or ($level !== "null")) {` will be true very often ^^ because if there is a # in it  and something else (what you obviously don't want) than its not NULL and would be true! Guess it should be `if ((strpos($level,'#') !== false) && ($level !== "null")) {`

Comment: Also, you may should check the give array order. Because I think you source may works but you override the result. If the order is `testValue2`,`testValue1` than this could be the reason since you checking for email.

Comment: Thank you guys for exhaustive answers! I look everywhere and actually i found this problem. First sql in the foreach i miss ' before WHERE! Oh my goodness

Answer (score 0):

as [stated by op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623971/foreach-exploded-string-is-stopped#comment45557039_28623971), there's a single quote missing in this statement, before the where:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE makleri SET level = '".$mesto."#rok', od = '".$od."#0"."', do = '".$do."#".$delka." WHERE email = '".$email."'");
```